# How to typecast timestamp_ntz to CST format using Spark/PySpark while writing to Snowflake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As we know we have 3 timestamps in Snowflake,

1. TIMESTAMP_NTZ
2. TIMESTAMP_LTZ
3. TIMESTAMP_TZ

So while writing timestamp to snowflake table, it bydefault takes as TIMESTAMP_NTZ.
How snowflake can take the timestamp in CST timezone while writing to snowflake table?

Comment: Can you add more details around what you are trying to do?  What statements are you executing and what your data looks like?  What "by default takes TIMESTAMP_NTZ"?  By default, Snowflake will use whatever your field definition is, so I'm unclear as to the reference you are making there.

Comment: I am taking current timestamp and directly storing that into snowflake. And when I check the datatype of that column in snowflake, it shows as TIMESTAMP_NTZ.

Comment: current_timestamp() function returns TIMESTAMP_LTZ, so perhaps your table was pre-defined as TIMESTAMP_NTZ?  But this detail isn't in your question, so hard to guess at an answer.

Comment: I directly create table from spark end while storing the data. And I want to tell snowflake that treat my timestamp column as CST format. Any help buddy

Comment: My snowflake timezone is set to 'America/Los angeles:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's important to know what timezone has been set as the default for your account/session:

```
SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'TIMEZONE';
```

Then change the default for your session to CST

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'America/Chicago';
```

And thereafter any selects of current_timestamp will be providing the data in the right timezone

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This is a great article for reference:
[Snowflake timestamp datatype ref](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz)

Assuming you have control over the precise column type in your table, I found that TIMESTAMP_TZ is how you want to define your table. Here's working example of everything I did:

```
alter session set timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
create or replace table ts_test(rn number, ts timestamp_tz);

insert into ts_test values(1, current_timestamp());
insert into ts_test values(2, '2019-12-10 07:50:00 -06:00');
insert into ts_test values(3, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Chicago', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()));

select * from ts_test;
```

if the timestamp is being generated in code, then make sure you include the UTC offset when inserting (rn 2).  If you're using the current_timestamp() which is LA, then make sure you convert to CST (rn 3).

if the table is being generated and you don't control the timezone default, then issue this first:

```
alter session set timestamp_type_mapping = timestamp_tz;
```

Comment: My code give the timestamp in CST in spark to snowflake but want to change that timestamp in snowflake to other timestamp_tz/TIMESTAMP_LTZ. How can I tell snowflake to treat my spark timestamp to CST format. Any idea buddy?